# Moodle Installation Error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-11.04, moodle

I have my moodle setup using this guide ( Ubuntu 11.04 ) http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Install_Moodle_On_Ubuntu_with_Nginx/PHP-fpm

I am having an issue installing moodle at this step:
moodledata dir does not want to intall

Hello I am having problem with installing the moodledata dir it is on a clean system only followed the guide above ( ubuntu 11.04 ) and it is complaining about isntalling the moodledata folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have created the directory in the right place (above docroot, so that it's not web-accessible) and that you have set it to be writeable by the webserver user. If unsure, set it to 777 like this and see if that works.

```
chmod 777 moodledata
```

If not, please paste the actual error message here.